# TokenMismatchException error on iOS 9.1 Safari

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I only get this  TokenMismatchException on mobile phone.

**iOS 9.1 / iPhone 6 Plus / Safari**

[image]

I've tried add this

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and this in my sign-in form

`{{ csrf_field() }}`

---

Not working on a my iPhone **(iOS 9.1 / iPhone 6 Plus / Safari)**

But I can still log-in the computer/laptop.

---

**HTML FORM**

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8888/sign-in" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="AMzt0uxA2vv79VGmR6WLtaVR5jGa9ZDbv07uI2Pb">
    <p class="pad-btm">Sign In to your account</p>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
            <input required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group text-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success text-uppercase">Sign In</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="AMzt0uxA2vv79VGmR6WLtaVR5jGa9ZDbv07uI2Pb">
</form>
```

**Does anybody know why this is happening ?**

---

**Updated**

It works on Chrome on iPhone 6 Plus iOS 9.1.

Comment: Thats because you are not sending csrf token in your post call, you will have to establish a simple GET call on your server, retrieve the returned csrf token and send it with your POST call as `_token` and it will work. or, simply disable csrf check

Comment: How  would I disable csrf check ? can you please answer it ?

Comment: Commenting out will work. I'm sure about that as I use the same way for my apps.

Comment: Disabling csrf is not the solution!! You should really be looking into why the CSRF token isn't being included in the POST data on mobile. What mobiles? Android/IOS? What versions? What browsers?

Comment: Have you tested other mobile platforms? Is it only iOS 9.1 Safari that is affected? Could you add the forms HTML to your question? Also how does the form work, is it using ajax? My main guess would be that safari is set to block cookies, you should probably check that isn't the case.

Comment: Chrome on my iPhone, log-in fine. You're right ! It might be only the Safari.

Comment: @Jeemusu : I've added my sign-in HTML Form, and the token seem to be there, and match, but that form, I grab it from Chrome on my Mac, and the log-in working.

Comment: How do I grab a HTML code out of my safari mobile app ?

Comment: @ihue  If chrome works then the problem is that safari is blocking cookies, it's just a setting in safari you need to enable.

Comment: @Jeemusu hmm. Okay. Trying that now. Thanks for your help. If it works you should answer it because you deserved it.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research on this Safari specific problem, I’ve learned I need to adjust our **Cookies** Settings.

**Steps:**

1. On you iPhone, go to `Settings`
2. While in Settings, Select `Safari`
3. While in Safari, Scroll down, Select `Block Cookies`
4. Change it to `Always Allow`
5. Done

Answer (score 0):

Based on you comment, and updated question, you can disable csrf check by editing `app/Http/Kernel.php` file.

Just comment out the class `VerifyCsrfToken` class from `protected $Middleware` array

**The second method:**

I'll add a small piece of code from my application and explain that.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(register_url);
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(token_url);
try {
    // first hit on the server url to get csrf token
    ResponseHandler<String> tokenHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    csrf_token = httpClient.execute(httpGet, tokenHandler);

    // Obtained Token, now we can make post call
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_token", csrf_token));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_device", device_id));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    ResponseHandler<String> mHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, mHandler);
```

This code belongs to one of my android apps (yeah, `DefaultHttpClient` is deprecated now). I have written a API endpoint that returns a csrf_token from the server i.e. `csrf_token` variable and url is stored in `token_url`. After receiving the csrf token, I use that for making my actual `POST` call by passing the `csrf_token` as `_token`.

I hope the code explains.

In your laravel code, you can return csrf_token as below

```
public function index()
{
    return csrf_token();
}
```

Comment: Hi mate, I've tried it I don't see that message anymore, that's **good** -  but now I can't log-in on my app anymore.

Comment: Disabling it may solve the problem, but it can open up a host of others.  You're disabling a security feature.

Comment: Yeah same concern, for my app, I made a simple get call to get the csrf token and used that for my POST calls. but that makes it 2 calls.

Comment: @VishalSh : Can you please show us the 2 steps, you're tallking about ?

Comment: @MatthewJohnson : I hope you don't mind provide a bit more suggestion by answering it. I hope you don't mind.